# Where did FrontDesk device come from

Tags: macos, windows-8, parallels

I have a Windows 8.1 virtual machine running in Parallels 10 on a MacBook Pro under OSX El Capitan. At one point today, I had a device show up in explorer under network locations...one I've never seen it before...called FrontDesk2. I couldn't "do" anything to or with it - couldn't remove the device, couldn't figure out how it got there. Icon on the device had a "Windows Media Player" logo. Nothing in installed software that resembles this.

Interesting - it is now gone.

Anybody know what this is? I can't even find a reasonable hit on Google.

Comment: Have you tried checking even logs for around that time when this happened ?

Comment: Interesting - there's a whole boatload of system time changes with "Change reason: System time adjusted to the new timezone". That's bizarre and unanticipated - but nothing else of note.

Comment: Have you been travelling ? Computer is acting like you moved it to a different location or connected to a network on different geolocation. Something happened for sure !

Comment: Also, does [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W90gu.png) ring any bells

Comment: We did travel out of state - two weeks back. There's no time change 'cept the daylight savings switch - that is - until today - at 4 am...then every 2 minutes. Gonna review all the scheduled tasks - see if I can find some evidence in there.

Comment: Re FrontDesk link you referenced, I saw/found references to that frontdesk, too. Not been doing any commercial real estate searches :-) I genuinely appreciate your digging though.